# R gsub remove pattern and return data frame format

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, gsub

I have a data frame below which included the regular expression and numbers and I want to remove the character behind the value EE. however, gsub or sub output is vector, not a data frame.

input:

```
C01 C02 C03 C04 C05 C06 C07 C08
98  EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302   EE|0.3302
99  EE|0.4050   EE|0.4050   EE|0.4050   EE|0.4050   EE|0.4050   EE|0.3818   EE|0.4050   EE|0.4050
100 EE|0.2199   EE|0.0000   EE|0.2199   EE|0.2176   EE|0.2199   EE|0.2199   EE|0.2199   EE|0.2199
102 EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449   EE|0.3449
105 EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669   EE|0.6669
107 EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352   EE|0.8352
108 EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309   EE|0.4309
109 EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634   EE|0.5634
110 EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969   EE|0.5969
111 EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486   EE|0.6486
112 EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616
113 EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770   EE|0.3770
114 EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616
115 EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218   EE|0.3218
116 EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402   EE|0.6402
120 EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944   EE|0.2944
121 EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616   EE|0.3616
```

output:

```
C01 C02 C03 C04 C05 C06 C07 C08
98  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
99  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
100 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
102 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
105 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
107 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
108 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
109 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
110 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
111 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
112 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
113 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
114 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
115 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
116 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
120 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
121 EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
```

Comment: `dat[] <- lapply(dat, gsub, pattern = "yourpattern", replacement = "")`

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% mutate_all(sub, pattern = '\\|.*', replacement = '')` or `df %>% mutate_all(funs(sub('\\|.*', '', .)))`

Comment: `dat[] <- sub("\\|.*$", "", as.matrix(dat))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop over the columns and use `sub` to match the pattern that starts with `\\|` followed by one or more characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`''`).

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, sub, pattern = "\\|.*", replacement = "")
df1
#     C01 C02 C03 C04 C05 C06 C07 C08
#98   EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#99   EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#100  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#102  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#105  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#107  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#108  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#109  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#110  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#111  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#112  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#113  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#114  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#115  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#116  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#120  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
#121  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE  EE
```